# Intersection point of two linked lists

Tags: c++, intersection, singly-linked-list

There are two singly linked lists in a system. By some programming error, the end node of one of the linked list got linked to the second list, forming an inverted Y shaped list. Write a program to get the point where two linked list merge.

Here is my recursive function for that -

```
int intersection(Node* head_ref1 , Node* head_ref2){
    Node* temp1 = head_ref1;
    Node* temp2 = head_ref2;
    if(temp1->next == temp2->next)
        return temp1->data;
        
    return intersection(temp1->next , temp2->next);
}
```

But it's not giving correct answer. Please explain why I'm getting the error.

Comment: This is because the length from the two heads up until the intersection point is not guaranteed to be same.

Answer (score 0):

```
Node *outer_head = head_ref1;
while(outer_head -> next != null)
{

  Node *inner_head = head_ref2;
  while(inner_head -> next != null)
   {
    if(inner_head == outer_head)
    {
     //Here it is merging occured 
    }
    inner_head = inner_head -> next;
   }
  outer_head = outer_head -> next;
}
```

**Complexity**

O(n1 * n2)

**Explanation**

The outer loop is for each node of the first linked  list and inner loop is for second linked list. In the inner loop, checking if any of nodes of the second list is same as the current node of the first linked list.

Comment: I guess you can do much better in terms of time complexity.

Comment: There was not  constraint about complexity in original question that's why I mentioned that it would take `O(n*n1)`

Comment: OP asks to explain why his/her linear time solution doesn't work. Instead, you propose a new quadratic time solution. I don't understand how this answers the question.

Comment: Someone already mentioned the reason in comment section , I just proposed another way if it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

The code below is O(max(l1,l2)) where l1 and l2 are the length of the lists. If you want to compare iterators rather than their values change *itr1!=*itr2 to itr1!=itr2;

```
auto itr1 = L1.rbegin(),last1=itr1;
auto itr2 = L2.rbegin(),last2=itr2;

for (; ++itr1 != L1.rend() && ++itr2 != L2.rend(); last1++, last2++) {
        if (*itr1 != *itr2) break;
}
```

When it exists the loop the last common value is *last1=*last2

Edit : I see that you have a singly linked list. In that case iterate over both lists and add the elements or pointers to a stack each then keep popping the stacks until the tops are different

Comment: I guess that `rbegin()` comes from `std::list`. How could you get one `std::list` that is linked into the middle of another `std::list`? It is impossible to form a Y-shaped structure with `std::list` or `std::forward_list`.

Comment: @Evg I am guessing this is a hypothetical question he was given in some class. Since it is a singly linked list most probably they wanted them to use two stacks which makes the algorithm O(max(n1,n2)) instead of quadratic.
Or the lists themselves do not have to overlap just their values

Comment: To me it looks like a typical algorithmic problem Google-like companies ask in their interviews. This problem can be solved in O(n) time and O(1) space.

Comment: O(n) time ok like the two solutions i proposed but O(1) space? care to elaborate

Comment: Compute lengths of the lists, `n` and `m`. Skip first `|n-m|` elements in the longer one, then walk in parallel. At certain step, you either reach the same node or last nodes in both lists.